# SQLCE: what does the following date time span mean?

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-ce

i am new to SQLCE, and i dont really understand some code lines in code that we use.
There is a database that logs and we try to retrieve log data, can someone help me what the following code retrieves which time spans ?, because somewhere in the logging we have a bug in time spans, but i am unable to read this format (i'm new to it)

```
d1 = (int)SqlHelper.ExecScalar("select count(*) from Report where OpenTime  > DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0) and type='0'");
```

Also there is another one

```
 d2 = (int)SqlHelper.ExecScalar("select count(*) from Report where OpenTime  between DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) and DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0) and type='0'");
```

UPDATE its SQLCE (server), an SQL database used in CE environments

What date time span is recieved for d1 and d2 ?

D1 should be a year total, but seams wrong

D2 a month total and also seams wrong ?

Comment: The first returns 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 in SQL Server. THe second returns 2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 and 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: Why is the zero in single quotes?

Comment: What is the datatype of the Report.Type column?

Comment: i dont know why it is in single quotes, i had no idea what these lines should return, i hope someone could tell me that. Because what we log doenst go right on some dates.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any DATEADD or DATEDIFF functions in the [sqlite language documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), but if you mean the functions in e.g. SQL Server, a quick google search will give you these [two](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) [answers](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp):

> The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates.

so `DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())` will return the time difference in years between 0 and now.

> The DATEADD() function adds or subtracts a specified time interval from a date.

so `DATEADD(yy,*your_time_difference*,0)` will return the date 0 with *your_time_difference* years added.

Similar for d2.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer, the former query selects a count where type = '0' and OpenTime is greater than midnight on the first day of the year; this should probably be amended to be `>=` (instead of `>`) to get the year-to-date.

Again, in SQLServer, the latter query selects a count where type = '0' and OpenTime is between midnight on the first day of the previous month and midnight on the first day of the current month; this should probably be amended to be:

```
OpenTime >= DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) and
OpenTime < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

- to get the previous month's count.